# Passing Jenkins environment variable with spaces to shell script

Tags: jenkins

I am unable to properly pass a variable with spaces in Jenkinsfile to shell command

I have tried using quotes (double and single) backspaces and various other combination. Jenkins will treat the string like as 2 item and single quoted them.

The variable in question in the Jenkins file.

```
MYTIME = 2022-01-02 03:04:05
```

In Jenkinsfile

```
    stage('list') {
      steps{
        sh script:'ansible-playbook -i ./hosts.ini ./ping_playbook.yml -e time=\\"$TIME\\" --limit ${ENV}', label: "ping test"
      }
    }
```

Jenkins will run it as

```
ansible-playbook -i ./lzhxjp-test-update/lzhxjp/hosts.ini .ping_playbook.yml -e 'time="2022-01-02' '11:22:33"' --limit sdktest
```

How do I put it so that Jenkins interpret it as `-e time="2022-01-02 11:22:33"`

Answer (score 0):

Inside single-quoted strings no variables are expanded by Jenkins (Groovy to be exact).

> Single-quoted strings are plain `java.lang.String` and don’t support interpolation.
> https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#all-strings

Thus it is passed directly into the shell and therefore already subject to shell quoting, you can remove the `\\` before the `"` and then the *shell* the will expand `"$TIME"` correctly.